# ansible Unsupported parameters for (command) module:

Tags: ansible, bash

I'm trying to run a shell command in an ansible task but I keep getting an error.

This is the task item and the shell command I want to run:

```
- name: Set File Watch Limit
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p"
```

But this is the error that ansible gives me:

```
fatal: [...]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (command) module: cmd Supported parameters include: _raw_params, _uses_shell, argv, chdir, creates, executable, removes, stdin, stdin_add_newline, strip_empty_ends, warn"}
```

The reason I want to run the command is because it will address a problem that reactjs/nodejs developers are facing when they use `npm run watch` as explained in this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763428/react-native-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached

How do I get ansible to run the command?  THe command works perfectly fine if I login to the server and manually execute it.

Comment: Are you sure the error belongs to this task?

Comment: Yup, i deleted all other tasks from my playbook, this is the only action to perform

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work with this

```
- name: Set File Watch Limit
  shell: "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p"
```

Comment: That is much cleaner looking ansible also.